# Avoid overlap when rendering images with webshot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, widget, overlap

I'm trying to shift elements out of the way for rendered images not to overlap with anything (trying to do it dynamically so that any size page fits and just pushed everything out of the way sort of)... Pretty new to this whole thing. Thank you in advance!

```
library(shiny)

library(webshot)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    fluidRow ( align = "center", h3("Screens"))
  ),

  sidebarLayout(
    #Side panel lay out to include variant, gene and disease info relevant to interpretation
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 h5("Screens")),


    mainPanel(
      textInput("screen1", h5("Screenshot1"), 
                value = "http://example.com/", width = "100%", placeholder = NULL),

      imageOutput("screen1"),

      textInput("screen2", h5("Screenshot2"), 
                value = "http://example.com/", width = "100%", placeholder = NULL),

      imageOutput("screen2")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$screen1 <- renderImage({
  webshot(input$screen1, zoom = 1, 
          file = "screen1.png") 
  list(src = "screen1.png",
       contentType = 'image/png')
})

output$screen2 <- renderImage({
  webshot(input$screen2 , zoom = 1, 
          file = "screen2.png") 
  list(src = "screen2.png",
       contentType = 'image/png')

})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is your problem. I do get a `webshot.js returned failure value: 1`.

Comment: Do you have phantomJS installed?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/vignettes/intro.html